# Where to deal with Thread interruption

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I have a Java 8 application where I run a task on a thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> { runTask();
                              finalizeTask(); });
t.start()
saveThread(t);
```

At some point, from a different thread, this task may be interrupted:

```
Thread t = getThread(); // Obtains thread t
t.interrupt();
```

With this, I want the `runTask();` line to be interrupted, but I'd still like the `finalizeTask();` to run.

How can I catch the thread interruption and deal with it?

Answer (score 7):

You can use try catch finally for this.

```
try {
    runTask();
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Log etc.
} 
finally {
    finalizeTask();
}
```

This will ensure that that finalizeTask always executes.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that unless `runTask` is waiting in one of the specific operations that throw `InterruptedException`, it will need to deal with the interruption by checking the flag.

Comment: I put `runTask` in a try/catch block, but it doesn't seem to be throwing any exceptions. The thread just stops running altogether.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `t.interrupt()` shouldn't called twice "to make sure runTask() is interrupted".